# Add Drop Shadow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm learning flutter on Youtube and I'm facing a problem to add Drop Shadow property to the textfield. Can someone tell me where exactly do I need to use the Materials Property to use the Drop Shadow function. I tried using it before the column, but it doesn't work. If someone can provide me with a solution with my code, it will be helpful

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: const HeaderAppBar(
          title: "Create Profile",
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 24.w,
            vertical: 35.h,
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    ProfilePhoto(
                      imgPath: widget.imgURL,
                      radius: 50.r,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 92.h,
                ),
                TextInput(
                  placeholder: 'Username',
                  controller: usernameController,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 55.h,
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Bio',
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  controller: bioController,
                  minLines: 4,
                  maxLines: null,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 122.h,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 63.h,
                  width: 327.w,
                  child: PrimaryButton(
                    f: () => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ChooseTeam(
                          id: widget.id,
                          email: widget.email,
                          img: widget.imgURL,
                          username: usernameController.text,
                          bio: bioController.text,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How about using Container's boxShadow or `PhysicalShape` widget

Comment: could you just tell me where do i exactly need to use it? @YeasinSheikh